# Android 4.1 unable to connect to Google Play but other wifi functions work - how to fix?

Tags: google-play-store, security, 4.1-jelly-bean, certificates

I'm using a Rikomagic 802III running Android 4.1.1, connected to my TV.  Until today, I was able to connect to Google Play, and my widgets were showing data.  Now, when I open Google Play, I get an error, after it indicates "Connecting", "Cannot Connect".

I've got some other widgets, like Google Analytics that also say "offline".  However, I am able to browse online through Chrome, and my account is linked.  When opening my analytics app, I briefly saw some exception error but haven't been able to reproduce.

When I go to Google.com in the default browser, I see an error indicating" This certificate isn't from a trusted authority" but it all appears to have Google info:

- Common name: *.google.com

I seem to recall some kind of Google certificate related issue on my desktop where I would see a similar error, and was told it had something to do with the system time.

Has anyone experienced anything like this and/or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the solution for this problem is the one I alluded to above.

The system date/time preceded the certificate's issue date, and I suspect that was causing the problem.

Setting the date to the correct date (or sometime between the certificate's issue and expiration date) seems to have solved the problem.